# Azure roles unhealthy (keep on recycling), but prevent me from doing a VIP swap

Tags: azure

I have a configuration of a Worker role, and a Web role with a few instances. Some of the instances seem to be unhealthy and it looks like they are constantly restarting.

The azure management portal gives the folllowing status:

**Busy (Starting role... Runtime is initializing. [2014-07-02T08:38:18Z])**

like.. constantly.

So I guess they are unhealthy for some reason. I've uploaded a new deployment to the staging server, but I can't do a VIP swap, because that gives me the following error:

**Failed to swap the deployments in cloud service poulescom.
Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on this deployment that requires exclusive access.**

So right now I'm in some kind of a deadlock, and can't get my healthy fresh version online without taking the whole site down!

Anyone know what to do?

[image]

[image: Azure instances]

Comment: Never mind. The problem just got resolved automatically. I guess there were problems on Azure. Too bad I just bought a technical support plan :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a major bug in the current implementation of Azure platform which can be reproduced by anyone at any moment the following way. Add this line as the first line of your role entry point `OnStart()`:

```
 throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

build and deploy the package into production slot. Then remove this line, build another package and deploy that one into staging slot. The one in the staging slot will run just fine, the one in the production slot will be recycling. That's the expected part. The unexpected part is that when you attempt a swap you face a *requires exclusive access* error message.

Now think of it the following way. What if the deployment in the production slot was recycling not because of a deliberately planted error but because of some unintended error which was not occurring until recently? Like it was working for several days and then some repeatable unhandled exception started being thrown in one of the instances and now your deployment is partially degraded.

What would you want to do? I guess you'd fix the bug, build a new package, deploy it into the staging slot and then try to swap. Doing so would lead to *requires exclusive access* error message all the time. You wanted to seamlessly swap deployment to prevent downtime but the function designed for this doesn't work on the very moment when you need it the most.

You can't *resolve* this in the current implementation. Either you wait till both deployments stop recycling (which is not guaranteed of course) or you can do the following:

- fix and redeploy the staging until it runs fine
- test the staging deployment
- (very carefully) delete the production deployment
- do the swap (yes, you can swap between an non-empty staging and an empty production slot)

The sequence above will cause you about a minute of downtime (and a lot of nerve cells lost) but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I thought that if you delete your Production slot, you lose the VIP to that slot? That scares me the most, because that would mean I have to wait until my DNS changes propagate to all the users...

Comment: @DirkBoer: Not sure if this is indeed a problem. I guess you could just text it on another service.

Comment: Well, some random guy here on StackOverflow says deleting a deployment will release the VIP. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17697650/647845 . Oh wait. That's you ;)

Comment: What do you mean with 'text it on another service'?

Comment: @DirkBoer: That's a typo. I intended to say *test* - create a yet another cloud service, deploy in there, run some clients that make use of it, then delete the production deployment and do the swap.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thanks, maybe I will next time it goes wrong. When I judge on your answer on the other question I don't have much hopes though.

Comment: @DirkBoer: When it goes wrong it'll be too late to test, won't it?